# Android Theme.Sherlock.Dialog dialog fill complete width

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using abs in my project. I have an activity defined in my manifest file, that i have given it Theme.Sherlock.Dialog style. This makes my dialog appear like a Dialog. however the dialog that appears fills the complete layout_width ? What am i doing wrong. Here is my code

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.ConfirmationDialog"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="Confirm"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeWithCorners" />

<style name="ThemeWithCorners" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_round_corners</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bodyText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/posotiveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_grey"
            android:text="@string/postiveButtonText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negativeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_grey"
        android:text="@string/negativeButtonText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I guess he / she doesn't want that the `SherlockFragmentDialog` fills the whole screen. Or am I wrong?
To your answer, the dialog only fill the whole screen if its needed. I use Sherlock dialogs in my apps as well.

Comment: Yes that is it. I dont want it to fill the whole screen. But i cannot get the wrap_content to work ?

Answer (score 3):

try changing following in ABS\res\layout\abs__dialog_title_holo.xml

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Change to

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

This worked for me.